# Compilation differences between Intellij, Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, compilation

I have a confusing Problem. At all first here is a minimal code example:

```
public interface I {
  <T> T getValue();
}

public abstract class AC<T> {
  private T value;

  public T getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

public class C extends AC<Integer> implements I {
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final C c = new C();
    c.setValue(1);
    final Integer i = c.getValue();
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

When I try to compile with javac or Intellij or Maven I get the Error:

> C is not abstract and does not override abstract method getValue() in I

If I compile the Program in Eclipse it compiles successful.

Can anybody explain me why eclipse can handle that and all other not?

Here my software versions:

- Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Intellij 2018.1.3
- Maven 3.3.1
- Oracle JDK 8u181

**UPDATE:**

I report this issue to Oracle and they can reproduce this issue. It is a bug in the Oracle Compiler ([Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8214700))

Comment: Maven and Intellij both use (by default) `javac` of the Oracle JDK, whereas Eclipse has its own Java compiler. Which compiler is right here is determined by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maven and Intellij both use (by default) `javac` of the Oracle JDK, whereas Eclipse has its own Java compiler.

Which compiler, **`javac` or the Eclipse compiler** is right here is determined by the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

I believe that the **Eclipse compiler is correct here**, as your example combines two things that work separately with both compilers without any problems:

- **Implementation** of an interface **via inheritance**, e. g.:

```
public class ImplementationViaInheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new C1().getClass());
    }
}

class SuperC1 {
    public void foo() {};
}

interface I1 {
    void foo();
}

class C1 extends SuperC1 implements I1 {
    // implements I1 via inheritance from SuperC1
}
```

- If **extending an abstract class without any abstract methods**, no method implementation is required (see also [Java Language Specification 8.1.1.1 - `abstract Classes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1)), e. g.:

```
public class AbstractClassWithoutAbstractMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new C2().getClass());
    }
}

abstract class SuperC2 {
    public void foo() {};
}

class C2 extends SuperC2 {
    // no methods
}
```

Comment: The separated cases are working, but is there a description in the language specification, which covers the combined case? I can not see it. Nevertheless, I think the eclipse compiler do it right.

Comment: The Java language specification generally does not contain combined cases. Moreover, the error message makes no sense because the code does not contain any abstract method (only one abstract class without any abstract method).

Comment: Thats not right. Methods from an interface are also abstract methods and the compiler fails with a equals error Message, if you do not implement a method from an interface.

Comment: Indeed, it fails with an equal error message. I would have expected _"...does not implement..."_.

Answer (score -1):

As you are implementing interface **I** from a non abstract class **C**, you need to override abstract method getValue(). Edit your class **C** to this:

```
public class C extends AC<Integer> implements I {
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

or you can implement **I** from class **AC** as you implemented the getValue() method there. And from class **C**, just extend class **AC**

```
public abstract class AC<T> implements I {
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
}

public class C extends AC<Integer> {

}
```

Comment: That makes sense however does not explain why eclipse is not complaining about it while maven and Intellij are.